# SAM (Sequence Alignment/Map) Format Alignment Tags

Tags: duplicates, tags, sequence-alignment, samtools

I am using samtools to remove duplicates. To mark and then remove duplicates markdup relies on ms
(mate score) and MC (mate cigar) tags that fixmates provides.

Does anyone knows exactly what are these tags? How is fixmates doing?

Comment: This type of question is to ambiguous for Stack you might get a better answer on the forums.

Comment: This is not a programming question so this is not the proper place to ask about it. Better try in bioinformatics.